# pip exhibiting strange git related error

Tags: python, pip, package

Whenever I try to run `pip freeze, I get the error

```
Error [Errno 20] Not a directory while executing command git rev-parse
```

and I do not understand where it is coming from. My `pip` version is 9.0.1, and it happens no matter where I run it from. However, `pip list` works fine, so there for some reason is a problem with fetching requirements.

Comment: Are you in a virtual environment? What's your output of `type pip`, and `type python`?

Comment: When you run "pip list" - do you have your project listed there? I had the same problem and it has been resolved by uninstalling my project with pip. (I've been playing with setuptools; that's why it ended up there.)